# Cannot Read Values Passed to Vertex Shader

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex-shader, vertex-buffer, vertex-array-object

I am trying to wrap my head around the various types of GLSL shaders in OpenGL.
At the moment I am struggling with a 2d layered-tile implementation. For some reason the int values that get passed into my shader are always 0 (or more likely, null).

I currently have a 2048x2048px 2d texture composed of 20x20 tiles. I am trying to texture one quad with it and change the index of the tile based upon the block of ints I pass into the vertex shader.

I am passing in a vec2 of floats for the position of the quad (really a TRIANGLE_STRIP). I am also attempting to pass in 6 ints that will represent the 6 layers of tiles.

My input:

```
// Build and compile our shader program
Shader ourShader("b_vertex.vertexShader", "b_fragment.fragmentShader");

const int floatsPerPosition = 2;
const int intsPerTriangle = 6;
const int numVertices = 4;
const int sizeOfPositions = sizeof(float) * numVertices * floatsPerPosition;
const int sizeOfColors = sizeof(int) * numVertices * intsPerTriangle;
const int numIndices = 4;
const int sizeOfIndices = sizeof(int) * numIndices;

float positions[numVertices][floatsPerPosition] =
{
    { -1, 1 },
    { -1, -1 },
    { 1, 1 },
    { 1, -1 },
};

// ints indicating Tile Index
int colors[numVertices][intsPerTriangle] =
{
    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 },
};

// Indexes on CPU
int indices[numVertices] =
{
    0, 1, 2, 3,
};
```

My setup:

```
GLuint vao, vbo1, vbo2, ebo; // Identifiers of OpenGL objects

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao); // Create new VAO
                            // Binded VAO will store connections between VBOs and attributes
glBindVertexArray(vao);

glGenBuffers(1, &vbo1); // Create new VBO
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo1); // Bind vbo1 as current vertex buffer
                                     // initialize vertex buffer, allocate memory, fill it with data
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeOfPositions, positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
// indicate that current VBO should be used with vertex attribute with index 0
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
// indicate how vertex attribute 0 should interpret data in connected VBO
glVertexAttribPointer(0, floatsPerPosition, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glGenBuffers(1, &vbo2); // Create new VBO
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo2); // Bind vbo2 as current vertex buffer
                                     // initialize vertex buffer, allocate memory, fill it with data
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeOfColors, colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
// indicate that current VBO should be used with vertex attribute with index 1
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
// indicate how vertex attribute 1 should interpret data in connected VBO
glVertexAttribPointer(1, intsPerTriangle, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

// Create new buffer that will be used to store indices
glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);
// Bind index buffer to corresponding target
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
// ititialize index buffer, allocate memory, fill it with data
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeOfIndices, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// reset bindings for VAO, VBO and EBO
glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);



// Load and create a texture 
GLuint texture1 = loadBMP_custom("uvtemplate3.bmp");

GLuint texture2 = loadBMP_custom("texture1.bmp");
```

My draw:

```
// Game loop
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    // Check if any events have been activiated (key pressed, mouse moved etc.) and call corresponding response functions
    glfwPollEvents();

    // Render
    // Clear the colorbuffer
    glClearColor(1.f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // Activate shader
    ourShader.Use();

    // Bind Textures using texture units
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);

    //add some cool params
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
    float borderColor[] = { 0.45f, 0.25f, 0.25f, 0.25f };
    glTexParameterfv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BORDER_COLOR, borderColor);

    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "ourTexture1"), 0);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "ourTexture2"), 1);

    // Draw container
    //glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, numIndices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, NULL);

    glBindVertexArray(0);

    // Swap the screen buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
```

My shader most definitely works, as I can adjust the output by hard-coding the 
values from within the vertexShader. My suspicion is I am not passing the values correctly/ in the correct format or not indicating somewhere that the int[6] needs to be included per vertex.

I cannot read anything from my layout (location = 1) in int Base[6]; I've tried just about everything I can think of. Declaring each int individually, trying to read two ivec3's, uint and what ever else I could think of but everything comes back with 0.

The following are my vertex and fragment shader for completeness:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec2 position;
layout (location = 1) in int Base[6];

out vec2 TexCoord;
out vec2 TexCoord2;
out vec2 TexCoord3;
out vec2 TexCoord4;
out vec2 TexCoord5;
out vec2 TexCoord6;

//  0.5f,  0.5f,// 0.0f,   118.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, // Top Right
//  0.5f, -0.5f,// 0.0f,   118.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f,0.009765625f, // Bottom Right
//  -0.5f, -0.5f,// 0.0f,   118.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.009765625f, 0.009765625f, // Bottom Left
//  -0.5f,  0.5f//, 0.0f,   118.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.009765625f, 0.0f  // Top Left 

void main()
{

int curBase = Base[5];

int curVertex = gl_VertexID % 4;
vec2 texCoord = (curVertex == 0?
vec2(0.0,0.0):(
curVertex == 1?
vec2(0.0,0.009765625):(
curVertex == 2?
vec2(0.009765625,0.0):(
curVertex == 3?
vec2(0.009765625,0.009765625):(
vec2(0.0,0.0)))))
);
gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0f, 1.0f);

TexCoord = vec2(texCoord.x + ((int(curBase)%102)*0.009765625f)
, (1.0 - texCoord.y) - ((int(curBase)/102)*0.009765625f));
//curBase = Base+1;
TexCoord2 = vec2(texCoord.x + ((int(curBase)%102)*0.009765625f)
, (1.0 - texCoord.y) - ((int(curBase)/102)*0.009765625f));
//curBase = Base+2;
TexCoord3 = vec2(texCoord.x + ((int(curBase)%102)*0.009765625f)
, (1.0 - texCoord.y) - ((int(curBase)/102)*0.009765625f));
}
```

Fragment:

```
#version 330 core
//in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;
in vec2 TexCoord2;
in vec2 TexCoord3;
in vec2 TexCoord4;
in vec2 TexCoord5;
in vec2 TexCoord6;

out vec4 color;

// Texture samplers
uniform sampler2D ourTexture1;
uniform sampler2D ourTexture2;

void main()
{
color = (texture(ourTexture2, TexCoord )== vec4(1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0)?
(texture(ourTexture2, TexCoord2 )== vec4(1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0)?
(texture(ourTexture2, TexCoord3 )== vec4(1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0)?
(texture(ourTexture2, TexCoord4 )== vec4(1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0)?
(texture(ourTexture2, TexCoord5 )== vec4(1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0)?
(texture(ourTexture2, TexCoord6 )== vec4(1.0,0.0,1.0,1.0)?
    vec4(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f)
:texture(ourTexture2, TexCoord6 ))
:texture(ourTexture2, TexCoord5 ))
:texture(ourTexture2, TexCoord4 ))
:texture(ourTexture2, TexCoord3 ))
:texture(ourTexture2, TexCoord2 ))
:texture(ourTexture2, TexCoord ));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong in two different ways:

> ```
> glVertexAttribPointer(1, intsPerTriangle, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
> ```

Vertex attributes in the GL can be scalars or vectors of 2 to 4 components. Hence, the `size` parameter of `glVertexAttribPointer` can take the values of 1, 2, 3 or 4. Using a different value (`intsPerTriangle == 6`) means that the call will just generate an `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error and has no ther effect, so you don't even set a pointer.

If you you want to pass 6 values per vertex, you can either use 6 different scalr attributes (consuming 6 attribute slots), or pack this into some vectors, like 2 3d vectors (consuming only 2 slots). No matter what packing you chose, you'll need a proper attrib pointer setup for each attribute slot in use.

However, `glVertexAttribPointer` is also the wrong function for your use case. It is defining **floating-point** attributes, which musthave matching declarations as `float`/`vec*` in the shader. The fact that you can input `GL_INT` just means that the GPU can do the conversion to floating-point on the fly for you.

If you want to use an `int` or `ivec` (or their unsigned counterparts) attribute, you have to use [`glVertexAttribIPointer`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml) (note the **I** in that function name) when setting up the attribute.

Comment: Thanks!! I got it working with the first three. So if I wanted to pass the 6 ints as two ivec3 would I have to make another vbo for the second ivec3?

Comment: @RIanGillis: \*sigh\* Questions like yours are why I *despise* tutorials that intermingle buffer object creation and vertex attribute designation code. The number of vertex attributes you use has *nothing* to do with the number of buffer objects those attributes come from (well, except that one attribute can't come from multiple buffers, obviously). You could put all of your vertex data in one buffer if you wanted.

Comment: So what you're saying is I should instead adjust the stride and offset of the glVertexAttribPointer to skip over the last three ints then create another glVertexAttribPointer pointing to the same data, but with a different offset so it only picks up the last three. Thanks!